# How can i alter live agent to show previous chats to the end user if they are the same contact?

Tags: liveagent

How can we shows past chats to the end user in live agent?
I observed that past chats are available to the agent but how can I make it visible to the end user?
Is there a way to make live agent work like traditional messaging based.

Comment: This is very vague, at a high level I can tell you that you can show past chats to a visitor but you need to provide more details on your current implementation to give you some guidance.

Comment: I am using embedded service and basic live chat implementation. We are open to use any easy customization maybe using VF Page or lightning for achieving this? How can we proceed on this?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented something like this a few years ago. If your "visitor" is a portal user this should be simple, all you would have to do is to use the Id of the logged in user, query their past chats or cases/related object and show them in a custom pre-chat window (or anywhere you want to place it).

Comment: We want to show it inside the chat after the pre chat .... so the users can see it like a single stream of messages. Is it possible to do so, if so any code samples you might have from your existing solution will help, or a link to do similar changes.

Comment: I no longer have access to that code but this isn't hard. Although, I don't see why you would want to show this after the pre-chat form. Regardless if you want to show it in the pre-chat, actual chat window or post-chat window, you would need a custom window, the developer guide has examples of  customizations of those windows.